# How do I authenticate Genius API on Retool

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, retool

I want to use the Genius API on my Retool frontend. However I am rather new to using APIs and lack the knowledge on how to do the authorizations for APIs in general.
My questions are below:

1. Which type of authorization does Genius use, can you tell given the below screenshots of the APIs details? I asume OAuth 2.0
2. On the retool Resources setting form, under OAuth2.0 they ask for a couple of properties under Authenication, where do I get these:

- Authorization URL
- Access Token URL

[image: Genius API Details]

[image: Retool API properties menu]

Comment: In the [Genius API Docs](https://docs.genius.com/#/authentication-h1) there are `https://api.genius.com/oauth/authorize` and `https://api.genius.com/oauth/token`.